# unknown crypto, os, http, https library with angular 17 and new eslint build

Tags: angular, http, https, cryptography, esbuild

We try to upgrade our crypto app to angular 17 and new esbuild. Unfortunately we are running into this issue

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "crypto"

    node_modules/@toruslabs/eccrypto/dist/eccrypto.esm.js:1:23:
      1 │ import nodeCrypto from 'crypto';
        ╵                        ~~~~~~~~

  The package "crypto" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.
```

We have configured as before our paths in the tsconfig.json file

```
"paths": {
      "crypto": [
        "node_modules/crypto-browserify"
      ],
      "stream": [
        "node_modules/stream-browserify"
      ],
      "os": [
        "node_modules/os-browserify"
      ],
      "https": [
        "node_modules/https-browserify"
      ],
      "http": [
        "node_modules/stream-http"
      ],
      "url": [
        "node_modules/url"
      ]
    },
```

Unfortunately it seems this is just working for typescript files loaded under `src`, so files we have developed by our self. But the issue is thrown by a library we install and need. Its not just this library there are also others and its not just the `crypto` library.

```
node_modules/dropbox/dist/Dropbox-sdk.min.js:706:204:
node_modules/eth-lib/lib/bytes.js:7:201:
node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/lib/index.js:27:82:
```

IMO this should be a problem related to the angular esbuild bundler

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same problem but I don't know how to force esbuild to use `crypto-js` or `crypto-es`. 

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. I'm trying to sort it out via polyfills, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered similar issue and below are the steps which I took to resolve the issue.

Step 1.

Create a file name build-fix.js

Step 2.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./node_modules/fernet/fernet.js', 'utf8', function (err,data) 
{
  if (err) return console.log(err);

   var result = data.replace('require(\'crypto\');', 'require(\'crypto-browserify\');');

   fs.writeFile('./node_modules/fernet/fernet.js', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
   });

});

fs.readFile('./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);

 var result = data.replace('require(\'stream\')', 'require(\'stream-browserify\')');

   fs.writeFile('./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js', result, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
   });

 });
```

Step 3
In script section of your pacakge.json file add the below code

```
"postinstall":"node crypto-fix.js"
```

Step 4
Remove node_modules directory and run `npm install`

Hope this fixes your issues.